# Writing regional text on an image using java

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to write text over image in java.
Following is mmy code and is working fine when using English language. But I want to add language support for the same as This text is picked from a text input from user and i am encoding it using javascript `encodeURI` and decoding it in java using `URLDecoder.decode`.

```
public static void writeText(String label, String rgb , BufferedImage bi, float yAxis) {
        Font font = CustomFont.getFont(30f);
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
        TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(label.toUpperCase(), font, frc);

        Rectangle r = layout.getPixelBounds(null, 0, 0);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.getGraphics();
        Color fontColor = new Color(0,0,0);
        if(rgb!=null){
            try {
                String[] rgbArray = rgb.trim().split(",");
                fontColor = new Color(Integer.parseInt(rgbArray[0]), Integer.parseInt(rgbArray[1]), Integer.parseInt(rgbArray[2]));
            }catch(Exception e){
                logger.info("Error applying color ["+rgb+"]. Defaulting to [0,0,0]");
            }
        }
        g2d.setColor(fontColor);
        float x = (bi.getWidth()/2)-(float)r.getWidth()/2;
        layout.draw(g2d, x, yAxis);
        g2d.dispose();
    }


public class CustomFont {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomFont.class);
    private static Font fontBase;
    static {
        try {
            InputStream is  = new ClassPathResource("font/opensans-condlight-webfont.ttf").getInputStream();
            fontBase = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            logger.warn("Unable to load font <opensans-condlight-webfont> loading default");
            logger.warn(e);
            fontBase = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,20);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warn("Unable to load font <opensans-condlight-webfont> loading default");
            logger.warn(e);
            fontBase = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,20);
        } catch (Exception e){
            logger.warn("Unable to load font <opensans-condlight-webfont> loading default");
            logger.warn(e);
            fontBase = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,20);
        }
    }
    public static Font getFont(float size){
        return fontBase.deriveFont(size);
    }
}
```

I am using CustomFont class to match the font style from html UI.

This code is not accepting language other than English eg. वायु सेना

It just writes boxes over the image

Comment: If they're boxes, then your OS don't have those fonts installed, it is wrongly configured, or the font itself (Arial in this case) doesn't have fonts for those codes (eg. वायु सेना).

Comment: Try to just print the string that you got on the console or in the log. If you don't see the - is that Hindi? - text, it means that your encoding and decoding is not right. If you see the text, the problem is in the graphic rendering.

Comment: @m0skit0 Font doesn't have these language codes.

Comment: @AmitSharma Well, that's the problem then. Use another font that has those.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I can't see `is that Hindi?` but it is printing in hindi in the console.

Comment: @m0skit0 there is no font available with all the languages :( how i will be able to achieve this

Comment: You can use the right font for the language.

Comment: we are currently using many languages (more than 6) in our different web sites and this tool will be used in every of them. So can't specify a single specific font.

Comment: Well, take a look at [Gnu FreeFont](https://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/) and see if it covers all your languages and suits your needs. If not, collect some fonts that cover all those languages, and try to do some language detection of the string, to decide which font to use.